# How to vertically centre text and images in an LI

Tags: html, css, list, vertical-alignment

I have this list block ([SEE DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2suMw/)) and need to vertically centre the text with the icon so whenever I have more than 1 line of text everything stays in the middle of the LI. I know that other people asked similar questions here but none worked for me :(

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2suMw/)

Comment: this is what you need http://jsfiddle.net/ilmkamil/D2qE6/1/ ?

Comment: For some reason they don't get perfectly aligned on my end. Thanks anyways ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of the `display:table` properties by changing the following styles:

```
ul.quote-list li {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #2a80b9;
    border-top: 1px dashed #dbdbdb;
    line-height: 1.2;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

ul.quote-list li > a { /*please note the extra > here */
    color: #2a80b9;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:18px 0 18px 20px;
}

.right {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[Example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2suMw/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You can postion the text and the icon using `display: inline-block;` with a `vertical-align: middle;`. You also need to remove the `float: right;` from the icon.

Here is a quick [example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2suMw/4/). I've added a `width` and `padding-right` to the text just to make it look better.

Or use the solution from @ilmk in the comments :)

Comment: Thanks. I actually chose Pete answer as it seems more robust.